# Google Datastore NDB validate optional IntegerProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do you validate an empty form field string `''` to assign None to an IntegerProperty?

```
class MyIntegerProperty(ndb.IntegerProperty):
    def _validate(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            if len(value) == 0 and self._required is False:
                return ?????????????????
            try:
                value = int(value)
            except ValueError:
                raise BadValueError(u'{0} must be a valid ' 
                    'integer'.format(self._name))
        if value < 0:
            raise BadValueError(u'{0} must be ' 
                'positive'.format(self._name))
        return value

class Account(ndb.Model):
    posint = MyIntegerProperty()
```

[Docs say](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.ndb#google.appengine.ext.ndb.Property):

> Things that _validate(), _to_base_type() and _from_base_type() do not
>   need to handle:
>
> None: They will not be called with None (and if they return None, this
>   means that the value does not need conversion).

What I'm currently doing is manually handling the case:

```
if len(request.form[name]) == 0:
    delattr(entity, name)
else:
    setattr(entity, name, request.form[name])
```

can it be smarter than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator can either produce a property value or raise an exception, preventing the entity from being saved. From the [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#types) table:

> Will be called with arguments *(prop, value)* and should either return
>   the (possibly coerced) value or raise an exception. Calling the
>   function again on a coerced value should not modify the value further.
>   (For example, returning **value.strip()** or **value.lower()** is
>   fine, but not **value + '$'**.) May also return **None**, which means
>   "no change". See also [Writing Property Subclasses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/subclassprop)

But none of the above is what you actually desire, which is to delete the property. Note that:

- setting a property value of `None` (which would fail, for example, for an `IntegerProperty`) is not the same thing as deleting the property (perfectly OK for an `IntegerProperty`)
- setting a property value of `None` while using a validator could be tricky since returning `None` from the validator means `no change`.

So I believe you'll have to keep your current handling for this case.

Comment: Ok, I will keep my current solution. I would argue that if `None` is an invalid value for an `IntegerProperty` I'd expect my `account.posint is None` to return `False`

Comment: Probably related to why the validator won't be called with None.